# Master-Detail Relationship causing problems with creating Related Records

Tags: reporting, custom-object, error-messages, master-detail, account-teams

We have a custom object to log our Activities with Customers. Until very recently, it had a lookup to that account. To better serve our reporting needs, I changed that lookup to a master-detail. Now, my users can't create a custom object record, if they are not the owner of said account. Is this a natural problem? I'm at a loss and can't think of any work-arounds. Any recommendations?

I thought that Account teams would solve this problem, but does not.

This is the error that they receive:
[image]

Here is a link to a previous question that is related:
[Creating a Last Activity Date Formula Field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281446/creating-a-last-activity-date-formula-field)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the standard behavior for Master-Detail relationships. The access to the detail record is determined by the access given for master.

You can either provide access to the master records to specific users (through Sharing Rules) or you can maintain the lookup relationship between the two objects like you had and adjust your report to fit your needs keeping this kind of relationship.